# How to programatically click or invoke a javascript method using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I tried with no success:

```
webBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("alert('Hello World!')", true, null);
```

also tried:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("alert('Hello World!')");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `InvokeScript` you can only call functions already defined on page.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender
    , WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("alert", new object[] { "Hello World!" });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To fire events call [HtmlElement.RaiseEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.raiseevent.aspx) 
To click call [HtmlElement.InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5b41b0d.aspx) and pass "click" as the method name to invoke;